# Adobe Flash plugin always crashes instantly

Tags: windows-10, firefox, flash-player

No matter what I do I can't seem to get Adobe Flash Player working in Firefox period.  I get this error message saying that the Adobe Flash plugin has crashed and this happens instantly right when I open something within Firefox that requires flash.

I did everything I can in an effort to get flash working from installing and reinstalling to install a beta version of Adobe Flash Player but nothing works.

On Adobe's website where you can check if you have Adobe Flash Player installed or not and when I click on the Check Now button I see nothing but all black and my system information. I took a screenshot comparing it to Google Chrome so I can show you what I mean

[image]

If it helps I'm running Firefox version 55.0.3 (64-bit) in Windows 10.

Comment: So I removed your comment about not getting help at SU, and formatted your question, should help you get a more positive response to your question

Comment: Took a look at every question you asked here at SU, and you haven't accepted a single answer, and most of your questions have multiple answers.  So your lack of help here at SU seems to be overstated

Answer (score 0):

First, for security reasons, [Mozilla set Flash as "click to play".](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/08/11/firefox-55-makes-flash-click-to-run-fixes-security-bugs/)

Second, if it still does not work as described, uninstall Flash, uninstall Firefox, rename your old profile, in case you wish to revert to it, and do a full, fresh installation without any add-ons. *Then* reinstall the standard current version of Flash.

That said, [be aware that Adobe is recommending users move to new technology.](https://www.theverge.com/2015/12/1/9827778/stop-using-flash) Unless there is some particular game that still requires Flash, it might not be worth the effort to install it.